# Bash script and manually running commands on the command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following simple bash script which takes input from stdin and prints the third line given as input.

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(cat)

echo $var | head -n 3 | tail -n 1
```

The problem with this script is that it prints all the lines but here is the funny part, when I type the commands individually on the command line I am getting the expected result i.e. the third line. Why this anomaly? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you delibarately using `cat` to input something and store into var ?

Comment: Can't you just shrink all of this to `sed -n '3{p;q}'` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

The aim of `head -n 3 | tail -n 1` is to keep the third line into variable
It will be more efficient to use read builtin

```
read
read
read var
echo "${var}"
```

Or to keep heading white-spaces

```
IFS= read
```

and not join lines ending with `\` or not give special meaning to `\`

```
read -r
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$(cat)` in your script. If script is reading data from stdin then just have this single line in your script:

```
head -n 3 | tail -n 1
```

And run it as:

```
bash myscript.sh < file.txt
```

This will print 3rd line from `file.txt`

---

PS: You can replace `head + tail` with this faster `sed` to print 3rd line from input:

```
sed '3q;d'
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell is splitting the `var` variable so echo get multiple parameters. You need to quote your variable to prevent this to happen:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(cat)

echo "$var" | head -n 3 | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, as far as I understand your question:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(cat)

echo "$var" | head -n 3 | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`var=$(cat)` will not allow you to escape out of `stdin` mode. you need to specify the `EOF` for the script to understand to stop reading from `stdin.`

```
 read -d '' var << EOF
 echo "$var" | head -n 3 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: That's a here-doc containing the `echo "$var"` line and delimited by end of file.

Comment: Accidental discovery. I always read about it but never took the pain to understand it :)

Comment: I mean, this will put the string `echo | head -n 3 | tail -n 1` into `var`, which is hardly what you want.

Comment: I have tried this and this works.. not sure hw dat would end up in var..

Comment: How are you running it? I don't see a way in which it *doesn't* end up as the content of `$var`.